# Django collection selection support?

Tags: django-templates

I am fairly new to Django and I'm curious if some functionality regarding selecting specific collection values in my templates.  What I'd like to do is something like this:

I have an object called content it has a key and a value property and i have a collection of that content object. I'd like to do something like this in my template:

```
{{ contentCollection.key["item1"].value }}

{{ contentCollection.key["item2"].value }}
```

rather than having to loop through it to get the key and then grab the value.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable you want to access has a dictionary interface you can use . to access the key values.

From the [documentation](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter04/) there is an example:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> person = {'name': 'Sally', 'age': '43'}
>>> t = Template('{{ person.name }} is {{ person.age }} years old.')
>>> c = Context({'person': person})
>>> t.render(c)
'Sally is 43 years old.
```

So you should be able to do this in your template (not sure exactly what your data structure looks like though).

```
{{ contentCollection.key.item1.value }}
{{ contentCollection.key.item2.value }}
```

Comment: I will definitely try that, the dictionary interface is probably the way to get it to work.